# Is there a port of python3-launchpadlib to 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, launchpadlib

I have a lot of scripts using [launchpadlib](https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib) to extract data from launchpad. Unfortunately those scripts had to be written with python2.x as launchpadlib was never ported to python3... till I read [this](http://blog.surgut.co.uk/2015/01/python-3-ports-of-launchpadlib-ubuntu.html).

So now a version of this package ported to python3 exists but it's only available for 15.04 (currently the development release).

Do we have some plan to backport this super useful package to 14.04? or better is there a ppa building `python3-launchpadlib` and its dependencies for 14.04?

Comment: You should probably ask the author directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A backport is now available in [zyga](https://askubuntu.com/users/13954/zyga)'s ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:zyga/launchpadlib-backports
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python3-launchpadlib
```

Source: [Backporting python-launchpadlib3 to Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.zygoon.pl/2015/07/backporting-python-launchpadlib3-to.html)